# Request desktop site in android webview

Tags: android, webview

I know this is a old question but I'm facing problem on some of the sites.

Here is my function to enable desktop mode on webview

```
 public void setDesktopMode(boolean enabled) {
    isDesktopModeEnabled = enabled;
    String userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
    if (enabled) {
        try {
            String ua = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
            String androidOSString = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().substring(ua.indexOf("("), ua.indexOf(")") + 1);
            userAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace(androidOSString, "(X11; Linux x86_64)");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        userAgent = null;
    }

    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(enabled);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(enabled);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.loadUrl(webAddress);
}
```

I'm just using `X11; Linux x86_64` in the user agent string to simulate it as a desktop.

For [google.com](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl) its working fine but for [this](https://www.awwwards.com/sites/cars-3) site its still showing the mobile version. I have checked it in google chrome with **request desktop site** enabled its showing the desktop site. I'm not getting what I'm missing?

I have tried this string also `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36` which I got reference from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent) but no luck.

Comment: Ask the developers of that site. Or, stick a proxy server between your device and that server and use that to see what Chrome is using for HTTP headers. Please understand that there is no magic setting that forces a Web site to serve any particular variation on that site, and please understand that "mobile version" and "desktop site" might be the same thing, controlled through CSS rules (e.g., media queries).

Comment: I will do check that proxy thing . Thanks for the idea

Comment: Please check this [headers] (https://pastebin.com/rdc3FbNU) . The only difference in both request is the user agent. This desktop agent does not resolve the problem in my webview  @CommonsWare

Comment: Then most likely the "problem" is that the Web site is using media queries or other techniques to determine the layout. Since that is what the developers of the Web site want, I suggest that you leave it alone, or talk to the developers of that Web site to discuss your plans and what you would like to see.